# How to pass a generic collection Class object as an argument

Tags: spring-mvc, generics, methods, collections, types

I've RESTful service Spring MVC based.
The service has a RESTful resource method that returns the following response:

```
public class OperationalDataResponse<T> {

    private String status;
    private String statusMessage;
    private T result;
    //getters and setters   
}
```

This response object encapsulates the result object of type `T`.

On the client side I use `RestTemplate` with `GsonHttpMessageConverter` added.
I get the response from service as a `ResponseEntity`

I handle the generic response with runtime `Type` as below:

```
public class OperationalDataRestClient<REQ,RESULT_TYPE> {

    public OperationalDataResponse<RESULT_TYPE> getOperationalData(String resourcePath, Map<String, Object> urlVariables, Class<RESULT_TYPE> resultType) {  
        //code to invoke service and get data goes here 
        String responseString = responseEntity.getBody();
        response = GsonHelper.getInstance().fromJson(responseString, getType(OperationalDataResponse.class, resultType));    
    }


    Type getType(final Class<?> rawClass, final Class<?> parameter) {
        return new ParameterizedType() {
            @Override
            public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
                return new Type[] { parameter };
            }
            @Override
            public Type getRawType() {
                return rawClass;
            }   
            @Override
            public Type getOwnerType() {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This works like a charm as long as my `resultType` is a non-collection class. 
So, this works great from caller code:

```
getOperationalData(someResourcePath, someUrlVariables, MyNonGenericClass.class)
```

However if my `resultType` is a collection (say, `List<String>` or `List<MyNonGenericClass>`)
then I don't know how to pass the `resultType` Class from the caller code.

For example, from caller code,

```
getOperationalData(someResourcePath, someUrlVariables, List.class)
```

or

```
getOperationalData(someResourcePath, someUrlVariables, List<MyNonGenericClass>.class)
```

throws compilation error.

I tried passing on `ArrayList.class` as well but that too doesn't work.

Any suggestion how can I pass a generic collection as a `resultType` from caller code (in other words, as an example, how can I pass the class object of a `List<String>` or `List<MyNonGenericClass>` from caller code ?)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that ResultType is coming as a List, Then it will obvious fail like you said compilation issue.Why? because you are trying to send a List when you method only accepts a single value.In order to over come that issue you will have to change the method arguments to the following

```
public OperationalDataResponse<RESULT_TYPE> getOperationalData(String resourcePath, Map<String, Object> urlVariables, List<Class<RESULT_TYPE>> resultType){
    ....
}
```

and you will have to make some slight modification to getType() Method,loop it and then pass each class value to getType method like so

```
for(MyNonGenericClass myClass:mylist){
    getType(OperationalDataResponse.class, myClass.getClass());
}
```